# Javascript Counting Sort implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, counting-sort

Is this a good way or the best way to implement Counting Sort in Javascript? 
Can't find a standard JS Counting Sort example.

```
function countingSort(arr){
  var helper = []; // This helper will note how many times each number appeared in the arr
                   // Since JS arrary is an object and elements are not continuously stored, helper's Space Complexity minor that n
  for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(!helper[arr[i]]){
        helper[arr[i]] = 1;
    }else{
        helper[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
  }

  var newArr = []; 
  for(i in helper){
    while(helper[i]>0){
        newArr.push(parseInt(i));
        helper[i]--;
    }
  }
  return newArr; 
}

var arr = [5,4,3,2,1,0];
console.log(countingSort(arr)); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: [The Wikipedia entry for Counting Sort shows the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), and links to at least one JS implementation.

Comment: [This google search for 'javascript counting sort'](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+counting+sort&*) provided me an implementation in js in the first link of the results.

Answer (score 6):

The code is correct, with some comments:

- In general, the use of `for..in` on arrays is discouraged, but unless you define enumerable properties on the Array prototype (which is a bad idea anyway), your use of it is fine to me
- You could improve the part where you loop to `push` the same value several times. This can be done in "one" go by concatenating `Array(helper[i]).fill(i)` to the results.

You could also use `reduce` to make the function more *functional programming* style. In the extreme, it could look like this:

```js
function countingSort(arr){
  return arr.reduce( (acc, v) => (acc[v] = (acc[v] || 0) + 1, acc), [] )
            .reduce( (acc, n, i) => acc.concat(Array(n).fill(i)), [] ); 
}

// Sample run:
var arr = [5,4,3,2,1,0];
console.log(countingSort(arr)); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: What is `, acc` in the first line of return for?

Comment: That comma is the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which evaluates to the second argument. This is a way to perform the assignment and then still evaluate to `acc` as return value for the arrow function. It is short for `=> { acc[v] = (acc[v] || 0) + 1; return acc }`

Answer (score 4):

counting sort is to start by initializing an auxiliary array of length k, that will hold the count of each number. Each index has an initial value of 0. After that, you loop through the input array and increase the “count” for each value by 1 every time you encounter that number in the array. Now, the auxiliary array holds the number of times each element is in the input array. The last step is to loop from the minimum value to the maximum value. In this loop, you’ll loop through each corresponding value in the count array, and add the elements who’s count is greater than 0 to the array in sequential order. You add each item by using a secondary incrementing variable (e.g. if we’re using “i” to loop from the min to max values, then we’ll use “j” to loop through the array), then increasing that second incrementing variable so the next item is placed in the next highest array index, and finally you decrease the value of the current item in the count array so that you don’t add too many of elements that value.

```js
const countingSort = (arr, min, max) => {
    const count = {};
    // First populate the count object
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        count[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    /* Now, count is indexed by numbers, with values corresponding to occurrences, eg:
     * {
     *   3: 1,
     *   4: 0,
     *   5: 2,
     *   6: 1,
     *   7: 0,
     *   8: 0,
     *   9: 1
     * }
     */
    
    // Then, iterate over count's properties from min to max:
    const sortedArr = [];
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        while (count[i] > 0) {
            sortedArr.push(i);
            count[i]--;
        }
    }
    return sortedArr;
};

console.log(countingSort([3, 6, 5, 5, 9], 3, 9));
```

Comment: Cool, this is also the only implementation here that does not depend on numeric keys in Javascript objects being sorted when iterated over. (while one can generally depend upon that quirk in newer environments, using it in an algorithm like this feels a *bit* like cheating to me, because the most important part of the algorithm, the sorting of the keys, is done behind the scenes, by the interpreter, rather than by the code-writer's programmatic implementation.)

Comment: This algorithm gives wrong output. Histogram needs to be prepared first, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

```
const countingSort = (arr, min, max) => {
    
  let counters = [...Array(max+1)].map(e => 0);
  let result = []

  for(let i = min; i < max; i++){
      counters[arr[i]] += 1
  }
  
  for(let j = min; j <= max; j++){
    while( counters[j] > 0){
      result.push(j)
      counters[j]--
    }
  }
  
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countingSort = (arr, min, max) => {
    const count = {};
    // First populate the count object
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        count[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    /* Now, count is indexed by numbers, with values corresponding to occurrences, eg:
     * {
     *   3: 1,
     *   4: 0,
     *   5: 2,
     *   6: 1,
     *   7: 0,
     *   8: 0,
     *   9: 1
     * }
     */
    
    // Then, iterate over count's properties from min to max:
    const sortedArr = [];
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        while (count[i] > 0) {
            sortedArr.push(i);
            count[i]--;
        }
    }
    return sortedArr;
};

console.log(countingSort([3, 6, 5, 5, 9], 3, 9));
```

```js
const countingSort = (arr, min, max) => {
    const count = {};
    // First populate the count object
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        count[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    /* Now, count is indexed by numbers, with values corresponding to occurrences, eg:
     * {
     *   3: 1,
     *   4: 0,
     *   5: 2,
     *   6: 1,
     *   7: 0,
     *   8: 0,
     *   9: 1
     * }
     */
    
    // Then, iterate over count's properties from min to max:
    const sortedArr = [];
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        while (count[i] > 0) {
            sortedArr.push(i);
            count[i]--;
        }
    }
    return sortedArr;
};

console.log(countingSort([3, 6, 5, 5, 9], 3, 9));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 8, 7, 7, 9, 2, 0, 1, 9];
let max = Math.max(...a);
let min = Math.min(...a);

function countingSort(arr) {
   const count = [];

   for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      count[i] = 0;
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      count[arr[i]]++;
   }
   const sortedArr = [];
   for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      while (count[i] > 0) {
         sortedArr.push(i);
         count[i]--;
      }
   }
   return sortedArr;
}

   
console.log(countingSort(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this problem you write like this:

```
const range = (start, stop, step) => {
    if (typeof stop == "undefined") {
      stop = start;
      start = 0;
       }
     if (typeof step == "undefined") step = 1;

  if ((step > 0 && start >= stop) || (step < 0 && start <= stop)) return [];

     let result = [];
     for (let i = start; step > 0 ? i < stop : i > stop; i += step) 
     result.push(i);
  return result;
};

const numbers = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5];
const max = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);

let count = Array.apply(null, Array(max + 1)).map(() => 0);
for (x of numbers)
    count[x] += 1;

let arr = [];
for (x in range(max + 1))
  for (i in range(count[x]))
    arr.push(parseInt([x]));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.